# How to deal with when I have to implement two model.fetch in one BackboneJS controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, callback, fetch

As the question I asked. BackboneJs provides a solution to ensure a fetch function completion, that is success callback. But how to make sure two different model's fetch function completed in one controller?
The situation is:

```
list : ->
  modelA = new ModelA
  modelB = new ModelB

  modelA.fetch url
  modelB.fetch url

  layoutView = new LayoutView
  viewA = new ViewA
    model : modelA
  viewB = new ViewB
    model : modelB

  app.main.show layoutView
  layoutView.regionA.show viewA
  layoutView.regionB.show viewB
```

If only one fetch function I can use:

```
modelA.fetch 
  url
  success : =>
    app.main.show viewA
```

But here are 2 different models.
Any suggestion?

Comment: you can try to use http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/ and on done callback show few views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go

```
$.when(modelA.fetch(),modelB.fetch()).done(function(){
   //Show the views here
});
```

Docs - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 0):

underscore.js -> after utility, is the answer

http://underscorejs.org/#after

```
var callbacker = _.after(2, this.render);
```

Assign callbacker to the success of both fetchs, callbacker will call render until callbacker is called two times.